# An exercise in category theory

Tags: category-theory

Consider the following commutative diagram in an Abelian category:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@.  A @>{f}>> B @>{g}>> C @>>> 0\\
@. @V{h}VV @VV{i}V @VV{j}V\\
0 @>>> D @>>{k}> E @>>_l> F,
\end{CD}$$

where the rows are exact. Prove that there is a morphism $p:C\to E$ such that $lp=j$ if and only if there is a morphism $q:B\to D$ such that $qf=h$

> We know by exactness that $gf=0,g=coker(f), lk=0, k=ker(l)$. I tried to use these to prove that $(B,i)$ is another kernel of $l$ in order to get a morphism from $B$ to $D$, but it seems that it does not work.  $\textbf{Hints are welcome}$

Comment: Richard, i just put in the two arrows you mentioned in the comment above.  Just to clarify, did you intend the two rows to be full short exact sequences (with 0 at either end)?

Comment: Hmm, in the $q$ implies $p$ direction, i was thinking, if $q$ exists, then $kq = i$ implies $lkq = li = 0$ by exactness of second row.  Then by commutativity $jg = 0$.  But $g$ is surjective by exactness of first row, so $j$ is the morphism $0_{CF} $.  Can't we then take $p$ as $0_{CE}$?

Comment: @DavidHolden I meant exactly what you put, the rows are not full exact sequences. The exactness means that $g$ is surjective, $ker(g)=Im(f)$, $k$ is injective and $ker(l)=im(k)$

Comment: In the category of abelian groups, take $A=D=0$, $B=C=E=F=\mathbb{Z}$, $g=i=j=l=\mathrm{Id}$. Then we can take $p=\mathrm{Id}$, but no $q$ exists.

Comment: @JulianRosen Sorry but I think that Justin's argument works, don't you agree?

Comment: @Richard Justin constructs a map $q$, but it seems that $kq\neq i$ for my example.

Comment: @JulianRosen You are right! I think I should have put $h=qf$. In this way I think Justin's proof works, do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $lp=j,$ we get $lpg=jg,$ and since $li=jg$ then $lpg-li$ is the zero map, so $l(pg-i)$ is too, so $pg-i$ is "in the kernel of $l$" (which we can't literally say since we're in an abelian category, and the objects may not be sets), but we do get $pg-i:B\longrightarrow D,$ so define $q=pg-i.$ If you're wondering why we can subtract the maps, recall that the morphisms $\hom(A,B)$ form an abelian group themselves.

A similar argument should work for the reverse direction.

Comment: By @JulianRosen's example I think I should have put $h=qf$. In this case checking I don't get why $h=-if$?

Comment: It's a little misleading to write $q=pg-i$ when really $q$ is the unique morphism such that $kq=pg-i$. Also, I think it should be $i-pg$ instead of $pg-i$.

Comment: @Richard To show that $h=qf$, it suffices to show that $kh=kqf$ because $k$ is monic. Compute $kqf=(i-pg)f=if-pgf=if$ because $pg=0$, and $if=kh$ by commutativity of the given diagram.

Comment: Yeah I've just deduced the final step exactly how you said, thank you very much !